# Is a marketplace of Square Online Stores possible?

Tags: square-connect

I want to develop a market place store front for farmers, but use Square as my payment gateway.  I have achieved this using Stripe, but they do not have the in-person payment option and that is crucial for the business model we want.

I would like to know do you allow application fees that go to the marketplace owner on transactions?  If not, how do you propose that a user of the payment gateway that is building a marketplace get paid. I need to pay the vendor AND the marketplace owner. I saw that with OAuth, you can connect to up to 10 merchants from your merchant account.  How am I supposed to use this information to get paid?

Can I create a separate fee transaction/transfer on a merchant account that goes into the marketplace account?  If so, I would incur the 2.9% +30 cent fee for a small transaction of maybe 40 cents.  Is there a way to avoid that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Square Connect API does not currently support additional application fees on top of API charges (aka "multi-party payments").

While the API *can* be integrated into your platform as an e-commerce payment gateway, it is not currently recommended for platforms that require multi-party payments.